# Spark Driver died, but did not kill the application

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a streaming job, which fails due to a network call timeout. Whereas the application keeps retying for some time, If in the mean time I kill the Driver, the application does not die. And I have to manually kill the application through the UI.

My question is:
Does this happen because the network connection forms over a different thread and does not let the Application die??